# Hide/Show button + not valid HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

First Question: On W3 HTML Validator I get the following error:

> Attribute value not allowed on element input at this point.

But, in my code, I am using the 'value' to change images so how could I fix this?

Second question: I need the image to remain the same even when I refresh. I am new to Javascript, but I know I need to utilise cookies or local storage in some way. Can someone help with this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").on("click", function() {
    $("#collapse").slideToggle("slow");
    if ($(this).val() == "Hide") {
      $(this).val("Show");
      $(this).attr("src","https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/2e83e2d35f0b889da7d5905c7bf574c2?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1");
    } else {
      $(this).val("Hide");
      $(this).attr("src","https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/2e83e2d00f0b889da7d5905c7bf574c2?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="image" value="Hide" id="button" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/2e83e2d00f0b889da7d5905c7bf574c2?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"></button>
<div id="collapse">
  Hello
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to make the HTML valid, the simplest tweak would be to use a class or data attribute instead.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").on("click", function() {
    $("#collapse").slideToggle("slow");
    if ($(this).data('status') == "Hide") {
      $(this).data('status', "Show");
      $(this).attr("src","https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/2e83e2d35f0b889da7d5905c7bf574c2?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1");
    } else {
      $(this).data('status', "Hide");
      $(this).attr("src","https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/2e83e2d00f0b889da7d5905c7bf574c2?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="image" data-status="Hide" id="button" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/2e83e2d00f0b889da7d5905c7bf574c2?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"></button>
<div id="collapse">
  Hello
</div>
```

To persist the value, retrieve the status on pageload and run the handler

```
const initialStatus = localStorage.imageStatus || 'Hide';
$('#button').data('status', initialStatus);
$('#button').click();
```

and set it after a change

```
localStorage.imageStatus = $('#button').data('status');
```

Comment: Thanks - that made it valid. But for the second question, I tried your code and it didn't work. I put the code in the same script

Comment: Sounds like you didn't put it in the right location. Put the code to run on pageload *on pageload* (not inside the click handler, after the `#collapse` exists), and set the local storage value at the end of the click handler.

Comment: I am still confused - I have   
else { ...
}
  const initialStatus = localStorage.imageStatus || 'hide';
$('#collapse').data('status', initialStatus);
  });
  localStorage.imageStatus = $('#collapse').data('status');
 });
</script>

Comment: Like I said, `set the local storage value at the end of the click handler` - don't set a new local storage value on pageload, that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: $(document).ready(function() { 
... 
localStorage.imageStatus = $('#collapse').data('status'); 
});

like this? where does the other code go?

Comment: At the end of the click handler - you know, the `.on('click', function(){` block? That's a click handler, its callback runs when a click event occurs

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/b0jswuah/1/ This is what I have - i tried moving the code outside and inside the 'click handler' but it doesn't work

Comment: Oh, the attribute is on the button, not the `#collapse` - so just change it to the button

Comment: It changes to the wrong color now? http://jsfiddle.net/2L0d64hv/1/